# Render a panelGroup after a valueChange of a hiddenInput

Tags: ajax, jsf, hidden-field, valuechangelistener

I want to render an `<h:panelGroup>` after a valueChange of a hidden input:

```
    <h:inputHidden id="code" valueChangeListener="bean.myFunc()" />
    ...
    <h:panelGroup id="block">...</h:panelGroup>
```

How can I do it? I can't add an `<f:ajax>` inside the `<h:inputHidden>` because it's a non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent.

Thanks!

Comment: how are you chaning the content of code? Also keep in mind, that you cannot "update/render" an element of which the `rendered`-attribute's  expression has been evaluated to `false` - you can only target a wrapping element, so the rendered-condition of the childs are evaluated again and then might turn to true depending on the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to the list of components to render from the server side, inside `myFunc()` using the `PartialViewContext`

```
FacesContext cxt = FacesContext.getInstance();
PartialViewContext partialCtxt = ctxt.getPartialViewContext();
partialCtxt.getRenderIds.add("block"); //adds the block to the list of items to be ajax-rendered
```